# SXA - Import Fails Due to Missing Language Information

Tags: sxa

I've got a simple scenario.  I export a site (single page), then try to import the exact same zip file.

I get an error that states:

> Could not find language information in the zip file. Please make sure
>   the package is importable.

I'm running Sitecore 8.2 (rev. 160729)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the content of your exported package (it might be a problem with export not import).
This error can be caused by:

- missing page item in the package (there must be at least one **index.html** file)
- First selected **index.html** has no information about exported language.

Open your package and if there is a **index.html** make sure that in the body element in class attribute there is a language information

Example body tag:

```
<body class="
{71E0EFC2-CC97-4066-B15F-7644972C4EFC} 
{en} 
{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3} 
[Ignore-This] sc81 preview default-device [Ignore-This-End] add-your-css-classes-here">
```

Comment: Looks like you're right - there is no index.html file.  I'll mark this as answered and open a new question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a new release just got pushed out there by Stephen Pope. Worth a look to see if it resolves your issue. https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Accelerator/11/Sitecore%20Experience%20Accelerator%2011%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes